# Performance overhead of casting from interface to implementation class

Tags: java, performance, interface, casting

Suppose I have an interface `Vehicle` and implementation `Car`. The class `Car` has a method called `getNumberCylinders()` that is not part of the `Vehicle` interface. Thus in my code I need to cast a `Vehicle` instance to class `Car` in order to call this method.

Does such a cast incur a performance overhead, versus the alternative of including this method into the interface and calling that method directly without the cast?

Comment: Casting doesn't do anything at runtime.

Comment: @DavidWallace So casting will have 0 nanosecond performance hit?

Comment: If `Vehicle` is an interface, then there's not really such a thing as a "`Vehicle` instance".  There'a an instance of a class that implements `Vehicle`.

Comment: @DavidWallace So the runtime check required by JVM Specification #2.6.8 doesn't happen? The *checkcast* opcode doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2):

> Does such a cast incur a performance overhead, versus the alternative of including this method into the interface and calling that method directly without the cast?

In this case, yes, because the object mightn't be a Car, so Java has to do a runtime check, which is how ClassCastExceptions can get thrown. JVM Specification #2.6.8.

If you have to do this kind of thing you're usually doing something wrong at the design phase. I would reconsider your object model.

Comment: The example is a little odd, but the issue is real. If OP had said "car has a trunk method and motorcycle doesn't" and they're both vehicles, that would be completely reasonable. However, I believe you're correct about the performance overhead, so I'm up-voting.

Answer (score 0):

If you think all vehicles should have 'number of cylinders', then it's good to add that method to the Vehicle interface. Otherwise, casting is totally fine. At runtime, casting doesn't modify your object at all. Casting has more to do with compilation check.
There is no obvious report on performance overhead due to casting operation, although Java specification itself does not guarantee it will be 0 nanosecond operation.
In my application, I'll worry more on the unnecessary database hits and object creation rather than just type casting.